# Code-errors or limits of deep type-inference in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

For exercise and learning/teaching, I've written TypeScript code to handle Matrices (up to 2 dimensions). They are generic wrt the type of their content/values, the number of rows and the number of columns. I defined `Dimension` as a type-alias of `number`. Thus, basically, we have an interface `Matrix<N extends Dimension, M extends Dimension, T extends MatrixContent>`.

This interface has several methods, for example:

- `add(other: Matrix<N, M, T>): Matrix<N, M, T>`
- `getColumn(idx: number): Matrix<N, 1, T>`
- `<O extends Dimension>withAddedColumn(other: Matrix<N, 1, T>, atIdx: number): Matrix<N, O, T>`
- `getTranspose(): Matrix<M, N, T>`.

The interface also declares properties `n: N` and `m: M`.
For `Matrix<1, M, T>` and `Matrix<N, 1, T>`, I have extended the interface to `Column` and `Row` to make the return types of getters more specific, and lock the values for the `n/m` properties to `1`. The return types for `withAddedColumn/withAddedRow` for Rows/Columns have a specific type of `2` for their respective generic type for the Row/Column Dimension.

The code does compile to JS, and works as intended - however, I'm getting various type-inference errors, and am wondering how to alleviate the problem.

On the class-name of the standard implementation of the interface, I get the error that the class wrongfully claims to instantiate the interface, since the type of the `m/n`-property for some arbitary chain of `getRow/getColumn`, `getTranspose` and `withAddedRow/withAddedCoumn` is not compatible with the return type inferred from the interface.

I am guessing it has to do with going from unspecified Dimension to specified Dimension (and back) - `N/M` to `1`, to `2/O` - but the return types are mathematically correct, and from a purely logical POV should work.

Is there something I can do to get rid of the errors (except supressing them)?

**EDIT**: Here is a minimal example which leads to some of the described issues:

```js
type Dimension = number;

type MatrixContent = number | Matrix<Dimension, Dimension, MatrixContent>;

interface Matrix<N extends Dimension, M extends Dimension, T extends MatrixContent> {
  readonly n: N;
  readonly m: M;
  getRow(idx: number): Row<M, T>;
  getColumn(idx: number): Column<N, T>;
  getRowData(): T[][];
  getColumnData(): T[][];
  getTranspose(): Matrix<M, N, T>;
  withAddedRow<O extends Dimension>(newRow: Row<M, T>, atIdx: number): Matrix<O, M, T>;
  withoutRow<O extends Dimension>(atIdx: number): Matrix<O, M, T>;
  withAddedColumn<O extends Dimension>(newColumn: Column<N, T>, atIdx: number): Matrix<N, O, T>;
  withoutColumn<O extends Dimension>(atIdx: number): Matrix<N, O, T>;
}

interface Row<M extends Dimension, T extends MatrixContent> extends Matrix<1, M, T> {
    readonly n: 1;
    getColumn(idx: number): Column<1, T>;
    getTranspose(): Column<M, T>
    withAddedRow(newRow: Row<M, T>, atIdx: number): Matrix<2, M, T>;
    withoutRow(atIdx: number): Matrix<0, M, T>;
    withAddedColumn<O extends Dimension>(newColumn: Column<1, T>, atIdx: number): Row<O, T>
    withoutColumn<O extends Dimension>(atIdx: number): Row<O, T>;
}

interface Column<N extends Dimension, T extends MatrixContent> extends Matrix<N, 1, T> {
    readonly m: 1;
    getRow(idx: number): Row<1, T>
    getTranspose(): Row<N, T>
    withAddedRow<O extends Dimension>(newRow: Row<1, T>, atIdx: number): Column<O, T>;
    withoutRow<O extends Dimension>(atIdx: number): Column<O, T>;
    withAddedColumn(newColumn: Column<N, T>, atIdx: number): Matrix<N, 2, T>;
    withoutColumn(atIdx: number): Matrix<N, 0, T>;
}
```

The compiler complains that calling `getTranspose().getTranspose().withAddedRow(...)` on a Row leads to a Matrix<2, M, T>, which cannot be assigned to a Matrix<O, M, T> - it cannot assign `number` to `O`. While number fulfills the constraints on O, O might be instantiated with a different type.

I can theoretically alleviate this issue by leaving out the specific generic Dimensions directly in the paramter/return-type and instead declaring a type parameter and equating that with the specific Dimension:

For example, on the Row interface, instead of
`withAddedRow(newRow: Row<M, T>, atIdx: number): Matrix<2, M, T>`, I can write `<O extends Dimension = 2>withAddedRow(newRow: Row<M, T>, atIdx: number): Matrix<O, M, T>`.

This removes the errors, but provides only a default generic type, instead of a true constraint, which I'm not really happy with.

There are further errors on the imlpementations (as I stated above), but they appear on the implementations of extending Mutable[Matrix/Row/Column] interfaces, which I am currently reducing to a minimal example. Until that's done - the above provides a good overview of the genreal issues and some specific errors.

I should note: While trying different variants of the code, I sometimes get the above kind of error, just on the properties `n/m` as specified, and sometimes I get "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite".

Comment: It would be helpful to also show the code and the errors you are getting.

Comment: In particular a minimal example showing **one** problem, because discussing many, unrelated ones in one answer will be a mess.

Comment: Please review the guidelines for what constitutes a [mre].  In particular, it would be very helpful if you give us some code that demonstrates your problem (and only your problem) when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  This lets people get to work diagnosing and fixing the problem instead of having to first re-create it.

Comment: Oh - you're all absolutely right of course. I edited the question with a minimal example leading to some of the described errors. I'll prepare and edit in an example with the other errors on the extending `Mutable`-interfaces and their implementations as soon as possible (though this requires 3 more interfaces and classes each, so might be a bit much).